# MyBatis Generator JavaModel extend key

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am generating a JavaModel with MyBatisGenerator.

If the primary key is one table, the following files were created.

- fields table Class
- Example Class

However, if the table has two or more primary keys, the following files were created.

- primary key fields table Class
- Non-primary key fields of the table (extends primary key field table Class)
- Example Class

why?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default configuration - if there is more than one key field, then a separate class is generated.

You can change it if you want to.  If you set `<context defaultModelType="flat">` then there will only be one model class regardless of how many key fields there are.

See this page for details: http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/context.html